# append map структур golang

Tags: golang, map

не могу разобраться как создать мап структур

```
var response map[string]msg
response["1"] = msg{mid:1}
```

и так не работает

```
var response map[string]msg
response = append(response,response["add"]msg{mid:1})
```

Comment: var response map[string]msg
    response = make(map[string]msg)
    var m msg
    m.mid = int64(1)
    response["asdasd"] = m
    fmt.Println(response)
    v,err :=json.Marshal(response)
    println(string(v))
Создает но при маршале выдает пустую структуру
{"asdasd":{}}

Comment: предоставьте минимальный пример, демонстрирующий вашу проблему.

Comment: @Ghost Для json поля должны быть экспортируемыми, то есть начинаться с заглавной.

Comment: Да это я и забыл

Answer (score 1):

```
var response map[string]msg
response["1"] = msg{mid:1}
```

Ваша проблема, очевидно в том, что Ваш мап response пуст. Т.е. это переменная типа `map[string]msg`, в которой нет, собственно, этого объекта.

Следует его туда положить:

```
var response map[string]msg
response = make(map[string]msg)
```

или

```
response := make(map[string]msg)
```

или

```
response := map[string]msg{}
```